# Converting anti-aliased to alised image in gimp

Tags: gimp, anti-aliasing, image-editing

I took a screen-shot of an image and want to edit it, but I am having a problem with edges, that it is ant-aliased. How can I remove anti-aliasing from that image??
I am using GIMP editor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problems are you experiencing in editing due to the AA?

Comment: In genaral you can not remove antialiasing, most of the time you wouldnt want to remove it either. Instead you would just alter your approach.

Comment: Without seeing the image, I don't think it's possible to help you much. Also, there is no real way to remove anti-aliasing from an already rendered/flattened raster image, not in GIMP or any software for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you usually want to keep the anti-aliasing.

If you want to remove it nevertheless, and if the image is on a uniform background:

#### 1. Remove the background using *Color to Alpha*

1. Add an alpha channel if necessary: *Layer → Transparency → Add alpha channel.*
2. Fuzzy-select the background
3. *Select → Grow* by two pixels
4. Use *Colors → Color to Alpha* to remove the background (note down the RGB values of the color you removed)
5. *Select → None* (important for what follows)

#### 2. Change the opacity using a layer mask:

1. Add a layer mask: *Layer → Mask → Add layer mask* and initialize to *Transfer layer’s alpha channel.*
2. Use the Threshold tool *(Tools → Color tools → Threshold)* to threshold the layer mask (it should normally apply to the layer mask at that point, otherwise, click on the layer mask preview in the layers list).
3. If/when happy with the result, *Layer → Mask → Apply layer mask.*

#### 3. Restore the background

1. Set the foreground color to the color your removed in the color-to-alpha step.
2. Set the *Bucket Fill* tool to *Behind* mode (*Mode:* selector at top of tool options), and bucket-fill the layer.